# Type assertion object literal typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, type-assertion

I'm trying to create an object of objects called `fields` of type `Fields`. This object contains objects of type `FieldTypes` which receives a generic and returns another type.

Creating object `fields`

```js
export const fields = {
  name: {
    label: 'Name',
    type: 'text',
  } as TextType,
};
```

My type file

```js
export interface Fields {
  [name: string]: FieldTypes;
}

export type Types = 'text' | 'select' | 'checkbox' | 'email' | 'number';

export type ValidationTypes = Yup.MixedSchema | Yup.StringSchema |
  Yup.NumberSchema | Yup.BooleanSchema |
  Yup.DateSchema | Yup.ArraySchema<{}> | Yup.ObjectSchema;

export interface FieldType {
  label: string;
  type: Types;
  initialValue: any;
  validation: ValidationTypes;
  placeholder?: string;
}

export interface TextType extends FieldType { }
export interface EmailType extends FieldType { }
export interface NumberType extends FieldType { }
export interface CheckboxType extends FieldType, CheckboxInterface { }
export interface SelectType extends FieldType {
  options?: Option[];
}

export type FieldTypes = TextType | EmailType | SelectType | CheckboxType | NumberType;
```

The problem that I'm facing is that when I'm creating the object `name` as a `TextType` I was expecting that the Typescript would show an error like `Object name is missing initialValues and validation properties` since It's declared on `TextType` interface.

The only way that I found that it works is defining a variable named `FieldName` and give it the properties outside fields, like that:

```js
const NameField: TextType = {
  initialValue: '',
};
```

Creating my object like this, I get the error `Type '{ initialValue: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'TextType': label, type, validation`

Answer (score 0):

You're using TypeScript's assertion feature wrong. Assertion has a few very specific use cases, and it should not be used to declare regular ol' variables and types.

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html#assertion-considered-harmful

> TypeScript's type assertion is purely you telling the compiler that you know about the types better than it does, and that it should not second guess you.
>
> ...
>
> However, you should be careful with your use of assertions... the compiler will not protect you from forgetting to actually add the properties you promised:

If you want the fields of your object to be of a certain type, then you should explicitly declare them so:

```
const name: TextType = {
  label: 'Name',
  type: 'text',
};

export const fields: Fields = {
  name
};
```

This way, TypeScript will give you an error on the line you declare `name` because it does not have the expected shape of `TextType`.

Also note that you should declare `fields` to be of type `Fields` because otherwise TypeScript has no way to understand that that is the expected type.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample is a good show case, why explicit type annotations should be preferred over type assertions.

> I was expecting that the Typescript would show an error like `Object name is missing validation`

[Type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) do their own compatibility checks, so you cannot accidentally cast incompatible types like `const t: string = 3 as string`. But they are more loose than explicit types and will check assignability in both directions: from the value/expression to the asserted type and vice versa! If one of these directions is valid, the code will compile. An Example:

```
const withTypeAssertion = {
  label: 'Name',
  type: 'text',
} as TextType // compiles
```

is valid. `{ label: string, type: string}` (widened `string` literal types) is not assignable/sub-type to `TextType`, but `TextType` is a sub-type of `{ label: string, type: string}`, so it will compile!
With an explicit type, we get the wanted error:

```
const withExplicitType: TextType = {
  label: 'Name',
  type: 'text',
} // error
```

So in essence, explicit types are preferable. For example you could annotate `fields` with following type:

```
export const fields: Fields = {
  name: {
    label: 'Name',
    type: 'text',
  },
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wGYEtgBsAmqcAvHAN4CwAUHHMgIYC2wAXOdbbbvQEZ5sByAHJNgAgDQdOMAJ5hWcATFAwJUgL5x6RACoqdc4JKrqA3NWqhIsOFmTKoGegmBwAYjgJFKNOAG0GZjZ0KDsAcwBdNg88fAN5VHMTCyoraHhZeTh44CJSJRUBOAAfRVQ8YARVEsUEAAtKgGseCBAi0oFgRnosXHbFZABXRj4oASTLcHTbe2BHZ1cYghz2X24+XGCYUOQwpNpMhRzEqTssGCx6XAA1K8GFemQZfbgANyusfHoLlDYhkbmLzA3BcdQgBDmAH4tjs9tR1Ck0jY7A4nC5svpDHAVMBkIR3J44liyHAEakpsjZvN0QBRbq9FY4vFEJZErIkslIjJY1nHEgYkAwFalOk9XA5FIAeklcAA7uc6nBDlpUOVYFgUERkBBsVAoNBqEg0PB5TA6jkAIKquY-ZD8nxcXj8RQiZhqXyHQTKQXuzTaAVCwxSmVhLCvVzYWJER7Y8C4LAIc5KwziOCoHWyx7KfC6-VQWxELrnbOTazwI3oOCRrxCYCy6KEvKrWiBBQOzjrZ3CUTuzjJ+RewrGWjqYxmYNwaBwUPh7HORXVnPlMD0KDfPAyLR2qzxxPc+SGzUmhU0uMJ845Nh6QUrUjtzubF094f9hQFH1joA)